# How to save file in root folder of android when app target to (Android 11 / API 30)?

Tags: android, kotlin

If we run the android app target to version 10 or below, we can set the below flag in the AndroidManifest file to access the root folder of the device.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: Are you referring to the root folder of the external storage directory? because the real root folder `/` is always read-only so you will never be able to write there anything on an unrooted device.

Comment: Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument` and allow the **user** to decide where on the **user's** device (or in the **user's** cloud storage) that the **user** wants you to store the **user's** content.

Answer (score 1):

it's not root folder of device/system, it's root folder of storage. On Android 11 you shouldn't and can't write to it, simply. Thats new policy of system, you can save files only in scope of your app. Some guide [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633867/how-to-save-file-in-root-folder-of-android-when-app-target-to-android-11-api)

if you REALLY need access to root of storage you can use new permission: [MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files). its not runtime permission, you have to pass user to proper system setting screen, besides that there is a big chance that your app will be banned/refused in Google Play Store due to its [policy](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play)